# Better margin control with Lyx?

Tags: lyx, margins

I want to control marginparsep in lyx, but I'm not sure how. The margin notes appear a little too close to the body text for my comfort, but I can't seem to do anything about it in the margins section. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/PaperLayout
All you need to do is add a texbox and put \layout in it to use that package. Then, you can tune the individual parameters as described in the link above.